# javascript window.open loses reference when app opens web application

Tags: javascript, window.opener

I do have an app (phonegap build) which opens (inBrowser) a webapplication. On logout i want to close the webapplication. But i can not get it to work. For instance:

```
var ref = window.open(url, '_blank', 'location=yes');
ref.close();
```

Does work; the url is not opened. However:

```
var ref = window.open(url, '_blank', 'location=yes');
setTimeout(function() {
            ref.close();
         }, 5000);
```

is not working.

Also this is not working if i call that in my web application:

```
window.opener.close();
```

It seems that as soon as the web application is opened, all reference to the app is lost.

Anyone knows how to solve this?

Comment: Hum... I don't know what your problem really is, but does [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/XRsQB/) help? Your code works for me...

Comment: Sorry, my question may be a bit vague. I hope this helps:

The window.open(url, '_self', 'location=yes') does work. My app opens the web-application (inBrowser). That is fine. But the reference to the app is lost directly after opening my web-application. So the window.opener.close() or ref.close() does not work.

Your fiddle does what i expected my code would do, but on a mobile device it does not.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work. The problem is that your browser is probably not allowing the script to open a new window. This is a config setting, usually set to prevent pop-up dialogs in most default browser installations. Check if you see any alert messages.

Comment: Thanks, but my window does open. I just can not get it to close again and return to my app.

Comment: Oh... ok, sorry about the misunderstanding. I think you should have mentioned that you are on a mobile device (as I see you do in a comment above). Well, you mention that you have an "app", but that doesn't necessarily mean that you are working on a mobile device. Which mobile device OS is it? Android, iOS or something else?

Comment: Also, `window.opener.close();` would close the window that opened the pop-up window. I am pretty sure that won't work. It did work "back in the days", but most modern browser will not allow this. It is a part of their security model. Some actions are not allowed or require a user interaction..

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you all.

Well, it is not possible indeed.

Because the App on the device is a local file and the web-application is a http file. And http can not access local files this way.

So the workaround is the have the App also online and instead of closing a window, rerout to the Apps url:  $(location).attr('href', '/app/index.html');